# PHP MySQL Check If A Table Has A Primary Key

Tags: mysql, primary-key

What would I query my MySQL server to check if a table has a primary key or not? Something like:

```
if(mysql_send("SELECT TABLE table HAS PRIMARY KEY") == TRUE) {
   // do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM TABLE WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this in an IF ? To obtain that if the index exists I do NOT execute the alter to create the index

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE table_schema = 'db'
     and table_name='table name'
     and column_key = 'PRI'
) As HasPrimaryKey
```