# How to check if primary key exists in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried several sql scripts but failed on it. Here is the one where I got close to:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE table_schema = schema()
AND   table_name   = 'my_table_name'
AND   index_name   = 'column_name';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP MySQL Check If A Table Has A Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982558/php-mysql-check-if-a-table-has-a-primary-key)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need below statement

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jbdzXwpWkYichsBL1ib2Rj/2

```
select constraint_name
  from information_schema.table_constraints
 where table_name = 'mytable'
   and table_schema = 'myschema'
   and constraint_name = 'PRIMARY';
```

or below
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jbdzXwpWkYichsBL1ib2Rj/3

```
SELECT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE 
     table_name='messages'
     and column_key = 'PRI'
) As HasPrimaryKey;
```

Comment: to get primary key column name
`select constraint_name
from information_schema.table_constraints
where table_name = 'messages'
and constraint_name = 'PRIMARY'`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_schema = schema()
AND column_key = 'PRI'
AND table_name = 'my_table_name'
AND column_name = 'column_name';
```

Comment: Why index_name? It doesn't exist in columns system table

Comment: It works with column_name instead of index_name.
My follow up question on this one is that when I drop primary key with `ALTER TABLE my_table_name DROP PRIMARY KEY;` the column still shows up.